# Create large content grid in Android

Tags: android, gridview, architecture, android-layout

I want to create a large grid for a android phone application where the size of the grid may vary from e.g. 10x10 to up to around 300x300. The content of each cell will be a test and some background (grid will eventually become skinnable).

I developed this earlier for iOS using `UIScrollView` and `CATextLayers` for labels, where the cells' content were loaded/unloaded based on their distance from the the visible section of the screen so that memory-wise it was always within a decent range.

What is the equivalent to this in Android applications?
I will be developing for 2.3 (and later for 4.0) and it should run both on phones and on tablets.

Answer (score 4):

Some info before making a decision:

- While in iOS `UIScrollView` goes in both axis, android's `ScrollView` just go in one direction.
- In Android you have a `GridView`, but, once again, I don't think you can scroll in both axis.
- In Android, widgets that work like a `UITableView` needs an `Adapter` that takes care of creating each of the views.

If I were you I would start reading:

- How [androidbigimage](http://code.google.com/p/androidbigimage/) project handles the scrolling through all the screen.
- How the `GridView` positions it's item in a grid and how it handles the variation of the grid size.

Once you get all that info, create a custom view similar to the `GridView` and start placing items using an `Adapter`.

PS: When you finish it, make it open source :)

Comment: HorizontalScrollView support horizontal scrolling. It may be possible to combine a ScrollView and a HorizontalScrollView